# .NET Resgen.exe file comment?

Tags: comments, resgen

Anyone know if there is a way to add comments to a file passed to resgen.exe?

Example:

```
ApplicationName=Hello World
ApplicationVersion=1.0
ApplicationMaker=Hello World Maker
;CommentHere
ValueYes=Yes
ValueNo=No
```

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9eey0h7(VS.80).aspx

Found the answer for this in case anyone comes across the need for it.  Just so happens ";" is the comment validator.